# The problem is putting one brick on top of another in Gazebo - bricks are jumping. How to fix it?

Tags: gazebo, ros2, gazebo-11, gazebo-model

Gazebo version 11.10.2
**The problem is putting one brick on top of another - bricks are jumping.**

I need this to simulate a robotic wall building process.

I made an experiment.

There are two pairs of bricks:
1st pair - primitive bricks, made of primitive boxes from standard Gazebo cube.
2nd pair - stel bricks,  made of stl file. I created stl file with the same geometry in Blender, export brick from Gazebo and then replace geometry information in the file to keep all settings the same.

So all bricks have the same geometry, mass, insertion and other settings.

**When I put one stl brick on another stl brick - they are jumping.**

3 other combinations works fine as expected:

- stl on primitive
- primitive on stl
- primitive on primitive

But I need to work with stl because real brick have a little more complex geometry.

I have tried to guess the physical parameters, to make it work well enough, but there are a lot of options.

Here are the code of sdf file of primitive bricks:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <model name='box_6_brick'>
    <link name='link_3'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.166667</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.166667</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.166667</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose>0 0 -0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.2 0.5 0.248</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='pixel'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <box>
            <size>0.2 0.5 0.248</size>
          </box>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <static>0</static>
    <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

Here are the code of sdf file of stl bricks:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<sdf version='1.7'>
  <model name='box_7_brick'>
    <link name='link_3'>
      <inertial>
        <mass>1</mass>
        <inertia>
          <ixx>0.166667</ixx>
          <ixy>0</ixy>
          <ixz>0</ixz>
          <iyy>0.166667</iyy>
          <iyz>0</iyz>
          <izz>0.166667</izz>
        </inertia>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
      </inertial>
      <pose>0 0 -0 0 -0 0</pose>
      <gravity>1</gravity>
      <self_collide>0</self_collide>
      <kinematic>0</kinematic>
      <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
      <visual name='visual'>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>/home/robot/Downloads/test_box_brick_blender.stl</uri>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <material>
          <lighting>1</lighting>
          <script>
            <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
            <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
          </script>
          <shader type='pixel'>
            <normal_map>__default__</normal_map>
          </shader>
          <ambient>0.3 0.3 0.3 1</ambient>
          <diffuse>0.7 0.7 0.7 1</diffuse>
          <specular>0.01 0.01 0.01 1</specular>
          <emissive>0 0 0 1</emissive>
        </material>
        <transparency>0</transparency>
        <cast_shadows>1</cast_shadows>
      </visual>
      <collision name='collision'>
        <laser_retro>0</laser_retro>
        <max_contacts>100000</max_contacts>
        <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
        <geometry>
          <mesh>
            <uri>/home/robot/Downloads/test_box_brick_blender.stl</uri>
            <scale>1 1 1</scale>
          </mesh>
        </geometry>
        <surface>
          <friction>
            <ode>
              <mu>1</mu>
              <mu2>1</mu2>
              <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
              <slip1>0</slip1>
              <slip2>0</slip2>
            </ode>
            <torsional>
              <coefficient>1</coefficient>
              <patch_radius>0</patch_radius>
              <surface_radius>0</surface_radius>
              <use_patch_radius>1</use_patch_radius>
              <ode>
                <slip>0</slip>
              </ode>
            </torsional>
          </friction>
          <bounce>
            <restitution_coefficient>0</restitution_coefficient>
            <threshold>1e+06</threshold>
          </bounce>
          <contact>
            <collide_without_contact>0</collide_without_contact>
            <collide_without_contact_bitmask>1</collide_without_contact_bitmask>
            <collide_bitmask>1</collide_bitmask>
            <ode>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
              <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
              <min_depth>0</min_depth>
            </ode>
            <bullet>
              <split_impulse>1</split_impulse>
              <split_impulse_penetration_threshold>-0.01</split_impulse_penetration_threshold>
              <soft_cfm>0</soft_cfm>
              <soft_erp>0.2</soft_erp>
              <kp>1e+13</kp>
              <kd>1</kd>
            </bullet>
          </contact>
        </surface>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <static>0</static>
    <allow_auto_disable>1</allow_auto_disable>
  </model>
</sdf>
```

I'll be very appreciated for any ideas and expert advice about Gazebo physics settings to solve this jumping problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid you need to tune your contact parameters. In particular, `kp` equal to `1e+13` a bit enormous for anything, there is any reason for use such a parameter?

As a starting point, I would suggest to:

- Check Gazebo Classic tutorial on how to tune physics parameters, for example https://classic.gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=physics_params&cat=physics
- Check existing models similar to the one you are trying to model, see for example https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/blob/master/cinder_block/model.sdf

As a general comment, there is any reason why you are using Gazebo Classic? That version of Gazebo will stop being maintained in 2025, and all users are suggest to migrate to the Modern gz-sim, see https://discourse.ros.org/t/gazebo-classic-end-of-life-and-migration-survey/35690 for more info.

Comment: The reason for use such parameters - because this is default parameters for cube in Gazebo, which just works fine but only for box geometry primitive. And the reason to use Gazebo Classic is just not enough time to migrate my project to gz-sim.

Comment: In this example https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/blob/master/cinder_block/model.sdf collisions are represented as geometry primitive type "box". I need to work with stl collisions.

Comment: Even if you are using `.stl` meshes, you can take inspiration from existing models to get some reasonable value for those contact parameter, see for example https://github.com/osrf/gazebo_models/blob/8163eb4b5e7e21985c6591d1c0bfb56468c0093f/drc_practice_ball_valve/model-1_4.sdf#L37 . In particular such a big `kp` can create problems. Note that another strategy you can use to reduce the numerical error (at the cost of computational efficiency) is to decrease the physics integration time-step, that reduces the numerical error introduced by the integration.